java.lang.IllegalStateException Sink.asPublisher(fanout = false) only supports one subscriber when using custom Playframework body parser as stream
After looking around stackoverflow and github issues, it seems this happened several times already in different contexts but never received any real help nor solutions so I try my luck once again.
We are using a pretty standard but custom Playframework bodyparser transforming the request body as a BinaryStream
private val streamParser: BodyParser[AkkaStreams.BinaryStream] =
  BodyParser { _ =>
    Accumulator.source[ByteString].map(Right.apply)
  }

that said, it randomly crashes while handling concurrent requests with forementioned exception. Indeed is seems a subscriber is trying to subscribe to the an already used publisher initially generated by the parser.
Under the hood it is creating a akka stream Sink then a Publisher then a Source with explicitly only one subscriber possible.
def source[E]: Accumulator[E, Source[E, _]] = {
// If Akka streams ever provides Sink.source(), we should use that instead.
// https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/18406
    new SinkAccumulator(
      Sink
        .asPublisher[E](fanout = false)
        .mapMaterializedValue(publisher => 
      Future.successful(Source.fromPublisher(publisher)))
    )
  }

Using the same code with fanout = true leads to another error not really helpful either:
akka.stream.AbruptTerminationException: Processor actor  [Actor[akka://application/system/Materializers/StreamSupervisor-0/flow-6131-1-fanoutPublisherSink#-1526957059]] terminated abruptly
Changing akka streams configuration seems to hide (as warning) or slow down the error's rate but doesn't explain why this happens:
akka {
  stream {
    materializer {
    debug-logging = on
    stage-errors-default-log-level = debug
    subscription-timeout {
      mode = warn
      timeout = 50s
    }
  }
}

}
The github issue linked in the library hasn't moved for few years now.
I must say that even after few days/week of investigation, it's pretty unclear why this happens, in what context and if we are running into a shared state or some kind of race condition issue.
We haven't identified any repeatable way to reproduce it either.
Here is the state of the Published when the exception is raised:
any tips, debug hints or help would be greatly appreciated!

more information came up after digging up akka and play issues:
https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/30908
it seems the exception isn't really labelled correctly as it is raised by the fact that the publisher's timeout is reached and then cancels by a CancellingSubscriber subscription.
The question is, is that an expected behaviour? why is the body parser cancelling?..

The stream publisher can't really be expected to hang around forever (that would be a leak).  Since it does seem that a subscriber eventually attaches, and that this happens under load, that says to me that there's a contention (or maybe a coherency, depending on what you're doing) delay (cf. Gunther's Universal Scalability Law).  Thread starvation on the Akka dispatcher is possible (e.g. from blocking) but it could also be semantic blocking: you don't subscribe until something else happens and that something else is slow under load.

thanks, as we have mainly blocking requests on the API side, play's thread pool configuration is something we need to look into indeed.

@LeviRamsey more on that matter:
after installing AkkaDiag library, implementing a custom dispatcher with proper threads pool size and throughput to 1, the warnings about thread starvation in actors disappeared but the sink.asPub error still appears randomly.
Would you have any other investigation ideas?
There is sometimes this warning appearing too
a.c.ClusterHeartbeat (xxx) [] Cluster Node - Scheduled sending of heartbeat was delayed. Previous heartbeat was sent [8607] ms ago, expected interval is [1000] ms. The reason can be thread starvation, CPU overload, or GC.

Assuming that the blocking has been resolved (note that if the tasks which are blocking also do some computation, that can result in starvation), that would point to suboptimal garbage collection or CPU overload (if deploying in a virtualized or containerized environment, it may be worth doing something like deploying half the instances with twice the vCPU per instance)

thanks, I'll have a look at the GC side. The thing is that locally on a macbook pro m3 pro (11 cores) the problem is easily replicable launching load tests but hard to trace back as it's deep inside akka's stack.

What's the cpu utilization like on that load test?  That points to CPU overload.

it's an 11 cores cpu and only one core seem overloaded by the jvm, with sometimes some load on the second core. Nothing saturated so far unless there should be some akka configuration to utilize all cores?
